# Enable domain wide delegation using the gcloud cli

Tags: gcloud, service-accounts

I have a makefile in which I use the gcloud CLI to create a service account and set roles. I also would like to enable domain wide delegation for this service account using the gcloud CLI. I can only find [instructions](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) on how to do this using the developer console. Is it possible to enable domain wide delegation using the gcloud CLI?

Comment: Hi, are you referring to [Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)?

Comment: Hi Braulio, yes thats what I am referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [gCloud SDK documentions of `gcloud iam`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam), there are specific coomands to set [`roles`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles)  and [`service-accounts`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts).

The commands available for [`domains`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/domains) are [`list-user-verified`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/domains/list-user-verified) and [`verify`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/domains/verify).

In this way, there is no way (yet) through the gCloudSDK to Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority.